# Async/Await mono crash

Tags: c#, linux, async-await, mono, serial-port

I'm using a serial port on MONO and Linux with async/await pattern, on the serial port base stream. Everything works fine, as far as the port exists. This is the async thread I'm using:

```
    private async Task ReceiverThreadRun(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int readBytes;
        try
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                readBytes = await this.stream.ReadAsync(this.receivingBuffer, this.receivingBufferIndex + this.receivingBufferCount,
                    receivingBufferSize - this.receivingBufferIndex - this.receivingBufferCount, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (readBytes > 0)
                {
                    ///do something
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Receiving serial error:  {0}", exception.Message);
            CommonHelper.Logger.Error("Receiving serial error:  {0}", exception.Message);
        }

        CommonHelper.Logger.ConditionalDebug("Exiting  ReceiverThreadRun");
    }
```

When I detach the serial usb module, everything freeze: App freezes, Linux freezes, mono presumably crash. The only solution is to restart the machine.

How can manage the port disappearance using async/await pattern ?

Forgot to say that the Task ReceiverThreadRun is started this way:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReceiverThreadRun(_cancellationTokenSource.Token), _cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Make sure on Serial Port you have handshaking turned off.  The locking I think is elsewhere since you have an exception handler in this method.

Comment: Configuration is: Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One, Handshake.None.

Comment: Are you using the vendors latest driver?  c# managed code usually doesn't lock up the PC.